# JSon array response on gridview in Fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, gridview

i'm new on android developing and i have to learn much much more. I have an activity that uses fragments. Opening main activity, it shows 3 fragments and using json i have created an Array that contains an ID and a Name. I haven't understood yet, how to put my array data in a gridview and then how use it on a fragment. Can someone help me? Here my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
String myJSON;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;



private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "result";
private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Nome";


JSONArray serv_man = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tableList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getData();


    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

     mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {           actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
    }
}
protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        serv_man = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<serv_man.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = serv_man.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

            HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

            persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
            persons.put(TAG_ID, id);
            tableList.add(persons);
        }
```

// Here i should create view but i don't know how yet

```
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite/get_collab.php");


            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.d("Log_Tag","xxx" + result);
```

// Here i can see that result is ok

```
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Obtaining list...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            pDialog.dismiss();
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new PpFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new ScndFragment();

                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new thrdFragment();

        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

// I should want to create a view with a gridview that shows Name and eventually a standard picture like a card view but probably it's really too much for me. I can only hope in your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't understood yet, how to put my array data in a gridview and
>   then how use it on a fragment.

To fill GridView with the data use Adapter.  [Official documantation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) describes what kind of adapter should you use for GridView and you can find many examples of adapters in the web.

If you want your Grid to be presented on fragment, rather on Activity itself, put Grid to Fragment, rather than Activity. It's the only difference.

For education purpose I advise you to fill Grid view in Activity (put it to layout xml) and add fragments later.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had seen official documentation, but it was very hard for me. In most cases, it's more simply looking at a code and study every row, testing, changing and verifyng differences. Unfortunately, many times, code you find on the web, is complicated for a beginner. I'm learning, and i have realyy much to learn! Thanks for your support and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can put your gridview and your http request in one fragment, such as PpFragment. And then you can init your gridview by using the data you get from the internet.

Here is the gridview adapter:

Part1:

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    public ImageAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tableList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return tableList.get(position);  //tableList is your data source
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){  
            //layout.item  is your item layout of your gridview
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);   
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.id = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            //name and id is your view of your gridview item, for the ID and NAME

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(tableList.get(position).get("aaaa"));
        holder.id.setText(tableList.get(position).get("xxxx"));
        //Here you can assign values to your TextView with the value you get from the data source.


        return convertView;
    }   
}
```

You can init your gridview below:

Part2:

```
//view is your layout of one fragment,such as PpFragment.
  GridView gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridviewss);
  ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
  gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

the gridview layout xml:

Part3:  R.id.gridviewss:

```
<GridView
  android:id="@+id/gridviewss"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:numColumns="3"
  android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
  android:verticalSpacing="7.5dp"
  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:background="#F1F1F1"
  android:paddingLeft="11.5dp"
  android:paddingRight="11.5dp"
  android:paddingTop="11.5dp"
  >
</GridView>
```

You can start your http request(the getData() method you pasted above) in the fragment method, such as onCreateView of your fragment PpFragment, and then you can init your adapter with Part2 code when you get the data from the host(After you invoke the method showList()).

I hope this could be helpful.

Part4:
  R.layout.frag_uno_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/id"
     />

 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/name"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then Fragment_Uno.java:

```
package com.example.stackproject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fragment_Uno extends Fragment {
String myJSON;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;


private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "result";
private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Nome";
JSONArray serv_man = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tableList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_uno, container, false);
    getData();
    return view;

}
protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        serv_man = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<serv_man.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = serv_man.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

            HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

            persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
            persons.put(TAG_ID, id);
            tableList.add(persons);
        }

        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frag_uno, null);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://etc.collab.php");

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.d("Log_Tag", "xxx" + result);
                //view is your layout of one fragment,such as PpFragment.


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PpFragment.this);
            //  pDialog.setMessage("Obtaining list...");
            //  pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            //  pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            //  pDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            //       pDialog.dismiss();
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private View layoutInflater;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public ImageAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tableList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return tableList.get(position);  //tableList is your data source
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }



    class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            //layout.item  is your item layout of your gridview
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frag_uno_item, null);
               holder = new ViewHolder();
               holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
               holder.id = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            //name and id is your view of your gridview item, for the ID and NAME

               convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
                          holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

         holder.name.setText(tableList.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));
         holder.id.setText(tableList.get(position).get(TAG_ID));
        //Here you can assign values to your TextView with the value you get from the data source.


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i have really apreciate. I tested your suggestion, making changes as you have written above, however i have some problem yet. In your adapter code, android studio highlights some code like this convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_pp_fragment, null) and tell me cant resolve method getlayoutinflater, then in Ppfragment in wich i have moved json string as you told me, GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview); is invalid, cannot resolve string view. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: In your fragment, you can use getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_pp_fragment, null), because you can just use context to invoke getLayoutInflater() mehtod.And view is your fragment's view,such as  view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_pp_fragment, null);

Comment: Thanks! Nothing is changed!! :-) It's normal, i am a bad student... if i change with getActivity() this time is just this red and compiler tell me cannot resolve method etc...

Comment: In my fragment, getActivity() can be resloved~ could you please show me your fragment code?

Comment: Thanks Lina, but i have made too many changes...:( blob...I'm creating a brand new project with fragment, and retry. Eventually i'll post the code.

Comment: I have read the code you pasted above and i run it in my fragment. This line " convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frag_uno, null);" should be changed to " convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frag_uno, null);", the method getLayoutInflater() should be invoked by our activity instance.You can try this "convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.XXX, null);" instead. I think this time the method getLayoutInflater is not red any more~

Comment: Hi Lina, have you seen new cleaned code posted yesterday.?  First problem, in getdata()  when i invoke the adapter, second just in adapter. Maybe with new variables new names and cleaned it's easier for you to find my error!

Comment: Fragment_Uno.java   and the gridview item layout is shown in the answer part4.

Comment: Forgive for my poor internet connection, i can't get data from your server~

Comment: You can try the code i add to the answer in part 4 to see whether you can compile the project or not.

Comment: Ok! I will do tomorrow... Today i need only relax!! See u soon

Answer (score 0):

First Change this

```
 public long getItemId(int position) {
return 0;
```

}

To

```
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
```

}

Then you need to iterate in hash map . 
holder.name.setText(tableList.get(position).get("aaaa"));
     holder.id.setText(tableList.get(position).get("xxxx"));`

Edited 
You dont need a hashmap for this forget it .. Just Create a molel Class and create entity and getter setter for it . And set the values and then pass a arrayList of its objects to adapter . Like Below example.

```
public class DataObject{

private boolean success;
private String message="";
private String hash;
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
}
public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}
public String getHash() {
    return hash;
}
public void setHash(String hash) {
    this.hash = hash;
}
```

}

And then When you are parsing .create a object and set params to it and add it in a ArrayList .Then pass it to adapter .Thats it and Your updated method looks like

protected void showList(){

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
    serv_man = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

    for(int i=0;i<serv_man.length();i++){
       DataObject dt =new DataObject();
        JSONObject c = serv_man.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        dt.setName(name);
        dt.setId();
        tableList.add(dt);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where`tableList=new ArrayList<DataObject>();`

define it at class Level and use it in your adapter class to get the text.like this ..

```
holder.textView.setText(tableList.get(position).getName());
```

Okay .let me if you face any problem

Comment: Compiler mark as error holder.name.setText(tableList.get(position).get("aaaa"));

Comment: And this is the brand new error log: D/Log_Tag﹕ xxx{"result":[{"ID":"1","Nome":"Gianni"},{"ID":"2","Nome":"Michele"},{"ID":"3","Nome":"Margherita"},{"ID":"4","Nome":"Cindy"}]}  E/log_tag﹕ Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Well, thanks for your explanation ADM, however everything i try complicates my position! If you take a look to my code, all is working until i have to call the adapter. So, since three days i'm asking to myself, where is my error, calling adapter or the adapter. If i debug and log all process, with code posted above, result is java.lang.NullpointerException. And i go in panic! Can someone create a custom adapter based on xml layout and json array? I'm just not be able...I surrender! :(

Comment: Use the above code and replace the line ..                                                    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frag_uno, null);          By                         LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);

Comment: Then sure it will work change that line in your adapter . otherwise i have to read all your code then only i can give you a solution

Comment: Ok, i think u have seen previous code, however, i have applied you suggest, no red errors, but i have noticed this: At the end of adapter code this two lines are in error, and i think this create failure in convertview.     holder.name.setText(tableList.get(position).get("aaaa"));
        holder.id.setText(tableList.get(position).get("xxxx")); on get in red error is cannot resolve get method - See code below where is adapter created by Lina

Comment: Did you created model class .or you still using HashMap .Crate a model Class which i have told in answer .

Comment: Never made. I have seen many example, but all of them works in different way. Can u made an example to use with my adapter? I thought something like public class Operatori {
    private String Nome;
    private String ID;

    public String getNome() {
        return Nome;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }
} But i don't know how to use it.